# ListView needs to scroll to last item when keyboard appears

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

```
<View id="body">
            <ListView id="list" bottom="80">
                <ListSection>
                    <ListItem title="List item 1"></ListItem>
                    <ListItem title="List item 2"></ListItem>
                    <ListItem title="List item 3"></ListItem>
                    <ListItem title="List item 4"></ListItem>
                    <ListItem title="List item 5"></ListItem>
                    <ListItem title="List item 6"></ListItem>
                    <ListItem title="List item 7"></ListItem>
                    <ListItem title="List item 8"></ListItem>
                    <ListItem title="List item 9"></ListItem>
                    <ListItem title="List item 10"></ListItem>
                    <ListItem title="List item 11"></ListItem>
                    <ListItem title="List item 12"></ListItem>
                    <ListItem title="List item 13"></ListItem>
                    <ListItem title="List item 14"></ListItem>
                    <ListItem title="List item 15"></ListItem>
                </ListSection>
            </ListView>
            <View class="h-size bottom" id="bottom_container" height="80">
                <View id="content_container" class="h-size">
                    <Widget src="com.careclues.buttons" id="template_btn"/>
                    <TextArea class="h-size" id="content" onChange="contentChanged"/>
                    <Widget src="com.careclues.buttons" id="camera_btn"/>
                </View>
                <Widget src="com.careclues.buttons" id="send_btn"/>
            </View>
        </View>
```

I have added $.list.scrollToItem(0, 14, {
        "animated" : false
    }); so that last list item is visible. When TextArea is getting focus last list item no more visible, how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try code this: 
`$.list.scrollToItem(0, 14, { "animated" : false });` 
in the onFocus event of TextArea.